# PHP Error in code of this contact form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am new to PHP and have been learning to build forms recently. I am able to get them up and running, following instructions on tutorial sites closely. But this, form I tried to build on my own by typing out code I remember that I learnt at w3c website. I am having trouble getting it to run. Please help me out..

This is the form's HTML code:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" id="contactform">

<label for="first_name">First Name<span class="error">*<?php echo $first_nameErr;?></span></label><br>

<input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="20" value="<?php echo $first_name;?>"><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name<span class="error">*<?php echo $last_nameErr;?></span></label><br>

<input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="20" value="<?php echo $last_name;?>"><br>

<label for="email">Email Address<span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?>*</span></label><br>

<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="35" value="<?php echo $email;?>"><br>

<label for="overview">Overview of project <span class="error">*&nbsp;<?php echo $overviewErr;?></span></label><br>

<textarea name="overview" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="5"><?php echo $overview;?></textarea><br>

<br>&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="art-button" style="zoom: 1;">&nbsp;
</form>
```

This is the form's PHP code, which is inside the same file as the HTML code:

```
<?php

function test_input($data){

    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    return $data;
}

function clean_string($string) {

    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}


// define variables and set to empty values
$first_nameErr = $last_nameErr = $emailErr = $overviewErr = "";
$first_name = $last_name = $email = $overview = "";

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "myself@mydomain.com";
$email_subject = "Contact us - My company's name";
{

if (empty($_POST["first_name"]))
{$first_nameErr = "(First Name is required)";}

else
{$first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);

// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name))
      {
      $first_name = "(Only letters and white space allowed)"; 
      }
    }

if (empty($_POST["last_name"]))
{$last_nameErr = "(Last Name is required)";}

else
    {$last_name = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);

// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last_name))
      {
      $last_name = "(Only letters and white space allowed)"; 
      }
    }

if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {$emailErr = "(Email ID is required)";}

else
    {$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

// check if e-mail address syntax is valid
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
      {
      $emailErr = "(Invalid email format)"; 
      }
    }

if (empty($_POST["overview"]))
    {$overviewErr = "(Overview is required)";}

else
    {$overview = test_input($_POST["overview"]);

// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$overview))
      {
      $overview = "(Only letters and white space allowed)"; 
      }
    }

}

//Email & SEND INFO
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Services: ".clean_string(implode(', ', $service))."\n";

    $email_message .= "Overview: ".clean_string($overview)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- Success HTML -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php

}

?>
```

Now, whenever I execute the code I am getting this error:
Call to undefined function test_input() on Line 48, which is the test_input() in the First name field of the whole validation process.

How do I resolve this error?

Thanks in advance.

I resolved the above error using the suggestion from larsAnders! Thanks for that!

I have updated the main code, according to the new code I am using.

But I have two new errors, for the new errors, I dont receive anything in my email, that I checked in the checkboxes, and also when I receive the E-mail, I am not getting who I got it from. This is the html code I am using:

```
<label for="service">Services required<br></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="web_design_services">Web Design Services</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="web_development_services">Web Development Services</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="web_identity_management_services">Web Identity Management Services</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="digital_design_services">Digital Design Services</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="web_video_services">Web Video Services</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="web_audio_services">Web Audio Services</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="content_management_services">Content Management Services</label><br>
```

and, this is the only line of PHP code I am using regarding the new error in the whole script:

```
$email_message .= "Services: ".clean_string(implode(', ', $service))."\n";
```

Please also tell me where I am going wrong in terms of not receiving the sender, in my E-mail. In all my earlier scripts it used to show sender as "Me".

Comment: why is your function bound inside of an if statement?

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. Sorry for my newbie PHP skills. Can you be a little more specific about what function you are talking? If possible could you tell me what needs to be corrected?

Comment: How do I correct that?

Comment: make a `function test_input($variable){ //some code }`, or just remove the test_input all together

Comment: `function test_input($input) { // do something to test input }`

Comment: I still cannot understand, how I should do that? Could you create the code for my form and tell me where to place it?

Comment: Just try moving the function to the top, outside of the `if else` statement

Comment: Will try that and notify ..

Comment: Still same error, but now on line I moved the code to.

Comment: Try to declare your functions before calling them and not after.

Comment: Post your updated code please

Comment: Code updated, please check now.

Comment: You should try to make your code a bit more readable with propper indenting and remove code that is not relevant to the question

Comment: @Xeli Working on that man..

Comment: @user3050570 I deleted my reply because I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, as in many languages, the order of things matters. So, when your script is executing, and it reaches a function call, that function must already be defined somewhere. First, define a function. Then, call the function. You can't just place a function anywhere (like inside an if block) and expect the code to search it out and use it. Make sure that your functions are all defined outside of any if blocks, because if the condition evaluates to false, the functions will never be defined. While you're learning, just keep all your functions together at the top of the script, outside any logic blocks. Start your script like this:

```
function test_input($data){

    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    return $data;
}

function clean_string($string) {

    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}

// define variables and set to empty values
$first_nameErr = $last_nameErr = $emailErr = $overviewErr = "";
$first_name = $last_name = $email = $overview = "";

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "sriprabhav@ymail.com";
$email_from = $_POST['email'];

$email_subject = "Contact us - Origin web designers";
//{ why are there stray brackets everywhere? if(condition){code} else{code}

if (empty($_POST["first_name"]))
    {$first_nameErr = "(First Name is required)";}
else 
    {$first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);}

    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name))
{
    $first_name = "(Only letters and white space allowed)"; 
}

 if (empty($_POST["last_name"]))
```

etc... as before...

For processing the checkboxes, you'll need something like this. This will define an array called $service:

```
if (isset($_POST['service'])) {
    $service = $_POST['service'];
}
```

And it can be placed right before this line:

```
//Email & SEND INFO
```

Then, when your code hits the $email_message .= "Services: line, it will have an array called $service to implode.

Comment: @Daedalus I know, and that's a lovely little demonstration, but just pretend for the sake of a newbie. Keep it simple. You can't learn everything the first day. I will edit my post to address the real issue, which is the if block.

Comment: One doesn't 'pretend for the sake of the newbie', one gives the correct examples the first time.  If you know its wrong, don't say its right.

Comment: That's fair. I respect that position. Especially with code. But if you haven't already, sometime come on down in the trenches and teach a few face-to-face classes with rank beginners. Then we can have a real conversation about what to do and what not to do for the sake of newbies.

Comment: Everything is working as expected, except, I am having two other problems now. I dont receive anything in my email, that I checked in the checkboxes. (I updated the code for that in a different block) and also when I receive the E-mail, I am not getting who I got it from.

Comment: @user3050570 Firstly, stop suppressing warnings on mail with the @ sign.  Secondly, where is this code being executed; on your local machine, or on an actual webserver on the internet?

Comment: I dont understand the phrase "stop suppressing warnings on mail with the @ sign". Sorry about that! It is being executed on an actual webserver on the internet. The address is http://test.originwebdesigners.com/contact-us.php, if you want to visit the actual page.

Comment: @user3050570 I recommend you check out the php manual; never just use code without knowing what it does first.  The @ sign, when placed in front of a function, suppresses warnings that function may emit with incorrect use or the like.

Comment: This line:
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  should just be mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  For the email from address, you need to define the variable $email_from somewhere. So right before this line: $email_to = "myself@mydomain.com"; you need to set the variable $email_from equal to the POSTed email address like so: $email_from = $_POST['email'];

Comment: @larsAnders ok I understand that, I will try that and see.

Comment: For your checkboxes, the names are good. They are going to generate an array called service. But to process that array, you'll need a statement. I'll edit my answer to include a line for processing all those. Also, listen to @Daedalus when he says "never just use code without knowing what it does first." Crucial.

Comment: Yeah, I am taking every advice possible. So I have implemented @Daedalus's advice too and I am going through the PHP manual once again. With the code, you gave@larsAnders, I was able to get mails with the sender showing in them as "Me". Thanks for that man.

Comment: Thanks for everything dude. My form is up and running again. This was just a test form that uses checkboxes. Thanks again dude. You are the best @larsAnders.